# Django Signal or Callback from Mysql Events and Trigger

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-signals

I have MySQL event running on every month and deletes the old records.
While deleting the records I want to send the push notifications to the user.

Is there any way we can define it in Django to receive the deleted records ids from Mysql to send push notification to the associated users?

Comment: If you are using MySQL trigger you can run python code with it. So basically you need to write python script that executes in your django project environment.

Comment: alternatively, if that's an option, you can instead use celery-beat for scheduled events. And you can interact with all your django things from a celery task